# SharedMailbox PrimarySmtpAddress into MailboxSentItemsConfiguration

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I like to take the output from:

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox | Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress
```

and put it in to

```
MailboxSentItemsConfiguration "$SMTPAddress" -SendAsItemsCopiedTo SenderAndFrom
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your question, improving the formatting of the embedded code. If you have any further information or clarification, remember that on Stack Overflow we are encouraged to make edits to questions to improve them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$1 = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox | Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress

    Foreach ($Inbox in $1){
        $PrimarySMTP=$Inbox.PrimarySmtpAddress
        Write-Host $PrimarySMTP
        set-MailboxSentItemsConfiguration "$PrimarySMTP" -SendAsItemsCopiedTo SenderAndFrom
        }
```

We use variable $1 to fetch all the mailboxes we want to use in our loop.

We then use a foreach loop to loop through all the addresses that we have collected under the $1 variable

In the loop we look up the $inbox.PrimarySmtpAddress (what we just fetched though the get-mailbox command) and bind that to a new variable

We then pass that variable into the cmdlet.

Comment: thanks for come back to me I have try $smtp = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox | Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress
Foreach ($Inbox in $smtp){Write-Host $Inbox} and get this back @{PrimarySmtpAddress=test@test.com} I just need the address thanks

Comment: @BenStraker It should now work. I changed so it now binds $inbox.primarySmtpAddress (So it doesn't add the @{PrimarySmtpAddress=} to $PrimarySMTP and then we use that variable in set-mailboxsentitemsconfiguration